# Sorting a single linked list algorithm in C does not work(Bubblesort with swapping the Nodes, not the data is used)

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

currently i'm trying out some algorithms. The Bubblesort with swapping the data works fine, but when i try to use the swap adress function the program ends with an error. I hope someone can help me
The structure i use is:

```
struct Node_s{
int data;
struct Node_s *next;
};
typedef struct Node_s Node_t;
```

Thats my function to swap the nodes:

```
Node_t* swap_adr(Node_t *ptr1, Node_t *ptr2)
{
    Node_t *temp;
    temp=ptr2->next;
    ptr2->next=ptr1;
    ptr1->next=temp;
    return ptr2;

}
```

Thats the function which calculates the length of the list:

```
int len(Node_t* head)
{
    Node_t* temp = head ;
    int i = 0 ;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        i++;
        temp=temp->next ;
    }

    return i ;
}
```

Thats the BubbleSort funciton which does not work:

```
void bubbleSort(Node_t* head)
{
    int length=len(head);
    Node_t* temp;
    int i, j, swapped;
    Node_t* p1,*p2;


    for(i=0;i<=length;i++)
    {
        temp = head;
        swapped = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < length  - 1; j++)
        {

            p1 = temp;
            p2 = p1->next;

            if (p1->data > p2->data)
            {

                /* update the link after swapping */
                temp = swap_adr(p1, p2);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

The strange thing is, this code works, i don't understand why?

```
void bubbleSort(Node** head)
{
    int length=len(*head);
    Node** temp;
    int i, j, swapped;
    Node* p1,p2;
  
    for (i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
  
        temp = head;
        swapped = 0;
  
        for (j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) 
        {
  
            p1 = *temp;
            p2 = p1->next;
  
            if (p1->data > p2->data)
            {
  
                /* update the link after swapping */
                *temp = swap(p1, p2);
                swapped = 1;
            }
  
            temp = &(*temp)->next;
        }

        if (swapped == 0)
            break;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I have four nodes in a row, `A -> B -> C -> D`. I want to swap nodes `B` and `C`, so that the final structure is `A -> C -> B -> D`. How many nodes are pointing at different nodes than they were before?

Comment: If `B` now points at what `C` pointed at, and `C` points at what `B` pointed at, your new structure is `A -> B -> D`, with `C` "orphaned" `C -> C`. Of course, this is only if you're swapping adjacent nodes. If the nodes are not adjacent, you still get a problem, just not the same one.

Comment: So 3 changes have to be done, A->next=C, C->next=B, B->next=D. 
Can you post a code snippet which will do the job in a single linked list?

Comment: I would load `N` node pointers on to a list/array. Sort it using `qsort()`, then splice/link the nodes from index `0` to `N-1`.

Comment: @DominikPrer You should pass the addresses of the objects you want to swap. If your objects happen to be pointers, then you should pass pointers to pointers (i.e. double pointer).

Comment: @DominikPrer I'm not posting any code for you. My example in the comment also only considers swapping two nodes right next two each other. Consider the general case where the nodes are in any arbitrary position in the list. I recommend still only passing in the two nodes you want swapped -- but then performing a single scan through the list to find each of the two node's previous nodes. Consider the special case where the nodes are contiguous as well (make sure there's not a bug for that case).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap **addresses**, then you have to pass the **addresses** of the two elements you want to swap.

For example, if you want to swap pointers, which are basically *addresses*, then you have to pass the **addresses** of the *addresses*. Thus:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void node_swap(struct node **p, struct node **q) // Pass the address of (struct node*)
{
    struct node *tmp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = tmp;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node *n1 = malloc(sizeof *n1);
    struct node *n2 = malloc(sizeof *n2);
    
    n1->data = 1;
    n2->data = 2;
    
    printf("N1 = %d\n", n1->data);
    printf("N2 = %d\n", n2->data);
    
    node_swap(n1, n2);
    
    printf("N1 = %d\n", n1->data);
    printf("N2 = %d\n", n2->data);
    
    free(n1);
    free(n2);
}
```

Output:

```txt
N1 = 1
N2 = 2
N1 = 2
N2 = 1
```

---

**EDIT** You probably should avoid `typedef`ing your structs. But in case you insist on that, here's how your code should look like:

```c
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node  node_s;
typedef struct node *node_ptr;

void node_swap(node_ptr *p, node_ptr *q) // Pass the address of p and q
{
    node_ptr tmp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an *extra* variable for the *previous* node (i.e. the one *before* `p1`).

When you swap the `next` pointers in the loop, you have to change `prev->next` from `p1` to `p2`

Here is some refactored code. It is annotated. I've compiled it but *not* tested it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node_t;

void
bubbleSort(Node_t *head)
{
    Node_t *temp;
    Node_t *rhs;
    Node_t *lhs;
    Node_t *prev;

    // get list total length
    int length = 0;

    for (temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        ++length;

    // reduce length by one on each pass (the last element on each pass is
    // correct -- no need to rescan)
    for (; length > 1; --length) {
        int swapped = 0;

        // get the two pointers
        rhs = NULL;
        lhs = head;
        if (lhs != NULL)
            rhs = lhs->next;

        prev = NULL;
        int i = 1;

        for (; rhs != NULL; prev = lhs, lhs = rhs, rhs = rhs->next, ++i) {
            // no need to traverse the entire list on subsequent passes
            if (i >= length)
                break;

            // nodes are in sort
            if (lhs->data <= rhs->data)
                continue;

            // swap the node pointers
            temp = lhs->next;
            lhs->next = rhs->next;
            rhs->next = temp;

            // link previous node to new lhs (i.e. rhs)
            if (prev != NULL)
                prev->next = rhs;

            // new list head
            else
                head = rhs;

            // swap lhs/rhs so that the for loop works
            temp = lhs;
            lhs = rhs;
            rhs = temp;

            // say a swap was done
            swapped = 1;
        }

        // early escape if no swap
        if (! swapped)
            break;
    }
}
```